# How to stop sound from 1st activity when clicking on new activity

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I'm working on Media player App when I choose a song from the list it plays fine but when I choose another song the fist one doesn't stop playing .
I tried finish(); but didn't work .
its one Player Layout resource file and multiple Java classes.

```
 public void s2 (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(s1.this, s2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
       
        
        this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) class to play a song, you should add `player.stop()` call to your activity destructor.